# Why this autowired field is always null?

Tags: java, spring, repository

I have an entity with a private field `countryCode`. I want to add a convenient method in my entity class for setting the country code: it's possible to set the country code either with an CountryCode object or a string.

If the country code is set by string, a CountryCode repository is necessary. However, I can't get Spring to initialize the repository field. Even if I put `@Component` and `@Scope("prototype")` on my entity...

What am I missing ?

```
private CountryCode countryCode;

public void setCountryCode(String code) {
    this.countryCode = getByCode(code);
}

@Autowired
@Transient
private CountryCodeRepository countryCodeRepository;

private CountryCode getByCode(String code) {
    if (code == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("The country code cannot be null.");
    }

    // countryCodeRepository is NULL below...
    CountryCode finalCC = countryCodeRepository.findByAlpha2OrAlpha3(code);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not enough info: please add details of your configuration + any other associated classes

Comment: On the basis of the info provided I think your repository and/or entity is not getting component scanned hence not available for autowiring. Must be an issue with your configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your entity class is instantiated by some ORM framework and therefore not instantiated by spring. So spring can not autowire the fields automatically.

If so you have these option

- [Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable)
- if you are using hibernate you can write an PostLoadListener which also implements ApplicationContextAware
  get the AutowireCapableBeanFactory and autowire the loaded entities on post load.

Please provide more information.